# How can I calculate Equipment Stopped Time in Spotfire or MySql

Tags: mysql, calculated-columns, spotfire

I want to calculate Stopped time of the  Equipment.
If `DateTime` of `Class(Alarm=TRUE)=Class(Working=FALSE)` for the same Equipment
then  `Stopped Time=Working(TRUE)-Working(FALSE)` for that Equipment.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution depends on the consistency of the data in the way you have described it. Any deviations to that may lead you to a (very) different solution.

Start by finding the next Date and Time value using an 'OVER' statement:

```
[Next DateTime] = First([DateTime]) OVER (Next([DateTime],1))
```

NB: I'm using 'First' as the aggregation, but anything is ok because there is only one value returned.

Next, find the difference in time:

```
[Time Difference] = DateDiff("minute",[DateTime],[Next DateTime])
```

Next, find the rows which meet the conditions:

```
[Check Conditions] = (Concatenate([Class] & [Value]) OVER ([DateTime])="WorkingFalse, AlarmTrue") and ([Class]="Alarm")
```

Finally, show the stopped time for the correct rows:

```
[Stopped Time] = If([Check Conditions],[Time Difference],NULL)
```

[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24QyH.png)

Comment: Thanks!
It was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think when you say equipment stop-time you mean the down-time i.e the time for which the equipment was not working or was idle.

**Food for thought**

Measuring this time period accurately depends on a few factors,

Will the equipment report/store the timestamp every time it starts and stops due to whatever reason. If no then it becomes difficult to track, for e.g what would happen if the equipment reports the start time and just hangs in between or the power fails, it would seem like the equipment is working but actually it is not.

Now assuming the equipment reports the start and stop times and may be also sends equipment data at regular intervals say, every 1 minute you could do the following while calculating the downtime.

if the equipment is in started state then

Current time - start time = total time

total number of samples (received every 1 minute) = total minutes the device was working

so total time - number of data samples = idle time.

Hope that made sense and was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.